# Add gradient border bottom to <hr> data-content text

Tags: html, css, gradient

so far I have this < hr > with the About Me text in a data-content.

[image]

I want to add a linear gradient border bottom with three colors under the text "About Me" like it is underlined. I've tried setting the background in the .section-divider:after to a linear gradient and padding and all that but it ends up setting the whole background as a linear gradient.

HTML:

```
<hr class="section-divider" data-content="ABOUT ME"></hr>
```

CSS:

```
.section-divider {
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.section-divider:before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.section-divider:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this or a better way to do this hr with text aligned to the left better in general let me know, thank you!

```css
.section-divider {
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.section-divider:before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.section-divider:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<hr class="section-divider" data-content="ABOUT ME"></hr>
```

Comment: so you want linear gradient just on the text? have you tried anything with linear gradient?

Comment: If this answer helps you then please click on the check icon (correct answer) on my answer.

Comment: I wanted a linear gradient on an underline underneath the text "About Me", possibly using border-bottom. I have tried things with linear gradients but they make the whole background of the "About Me" a linear gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```css
.section-divider {
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.section-divider:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: #333; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#34495e), color-stop(10%,#34495e), color-stop(10%,#207cca), color-stop(24%,#2989d8), color-stop(24%,#34495e), color-stop(42%,#34495e), color-stop(42%,#207cca), color-stop(70%,#207cca), color-stop(70%,#207cca), color-stop(70%,#34495e), color-stop(100%,#34495e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #34495e 0%,#34495e 10%,#207cca 10%,#2989d8 24%,#34495e 24%,#34495e 42%,#207cca 42%,#207cca 70%,#207cca 70%,#34495e 70%,#34495e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #34495e 0%, #34495e 9%, #207cca 10%, #2989d8 24%, #34495e 24%, #34495e 42%, #207cca 42%, #207cca 70%, #207cca 70%, #34495e 71%, #34495e 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #34495e 0%, #34495e 9%, #207cca 10%, #2989d8 24%, #34495e 24%, #34495e 42%, #207cca 42%, #207cca 70%, #207cca 70%, #34495e 71%, #34495e 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #34495e 0%, #34495e 9%, #207cca 10%, #2989d8 24%, #34495e 24%, #34495e 42%, #207cca 42%, #207cca 70%, #207cca 70%, #34495e 71%, #34495e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
.section-divider:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<hr class="section-divider" data-content="ABOUT ME" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this makes the <hr> line a linear gradient, however I was looking to make the "About Me" text have a linear gradient underline, like a linear gradient border-bottom.